# "Syntax error, unexpected T_STRING" problem with goto

Tags: php, string, syntax, goto

http://www.faressoft.org/test/hello.php

My Code :

```
<?php
echo "hello World";
goto end; // this is line 3
echo "before end";
end:
echo "end";
?>
```

Error :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/alfalah1/public_html/faressoft.org/test/hello.php on line 3

**It works very well in my localhost but doesn't work in justhost server ? why ?**

Comment: For the last many years, goto has been declared the bane of good code everywhere.  There are lots of control structures you can use instead of this.  In the end, it makes code to follow.  I learned to code in BASIC where goto was normal, but since then I have not used this since.

Comment: @Surreal what does `throw` do, if not exactly the same as goto? ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> but doesn't work in justhost server ? why ?

Probably because the remote server isn't running PHP 5.3, which is the [minimum required version](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) for `goto`.

That said, using the `goto` keyword is generally regarded as an awfully, awfully bad practice from the olden days. I still think this got introduced in PHP because of a lost bet or something. I would not get into the habit of using it.

Comment: How can i know what is the php version ?

Comment: @faressoft `phpinfo();` or `echo PHP_VERSION;`

Comment: phpinfo() will tell you lots of useful information about both the server and PHP.

Comment: @faressoft: Create a php file with just the following content: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Open that file in the browser and you get all the information you need (and more).

Comment: @faressoft well, then it's clear why it doesn't work

Comment: On my PHP 5.5 server also getting this error but only if I fire script internally using cron. URL call works fine. Any ideas now?

Comment: @KrzysztofPrzygoda you may be running different PHP versions on the web server and when using the CLI (Command Line Interface).

Comment: OK, this is the clue... Does cron call read php.ini? I'm setting there php version. If not, how to force him?

Comment: @Krzysztof I may not be totally up to date here, but I'm not sure how you can set the PHP version in the php.ini file? Once that file is being read, the PHP interpreter is already running, no?

Comment: This may help http://superuser.com/questions/971867/why-is-the-php-version-different-in-phpinfo-and-cli

Comment: Thx Pekka! I found solution, i.e.:
1) CLI doesn't respect .htaccess directives where you can place php version override command,
2) command system('php55-cli script.php'); in script executed by CRON solves the problem.